# Drop-down menu is not working

Tags: jquery, joomla, mootools, zurb-foundation

I have zurb's foundation implemented in Joomla.

I've done everything as required by this page as demonstrated by first example: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html

And I've also added this just before body tag

```
    <script>
     $(document).foundation();
    </script>
```

It's still **NOT** working.

Wondering why ...

**EDIT**

Let me know what other information I could provide in order to troubleshoot this. I'm honestly at loss at why it's not working.

**/EDIT**

Here are the files that shows in in source code, wondering if it's caused by any form of conflict?

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/social/services/templates/testingdifferentversion8/css/normalize.css" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/social/services/templates/testingdifferentversion8/css/foundation.css" type="text/css" />
       <script src="/social/services/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="/social/services/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="/social/services/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="/social/services/templates/testingdifferentversion8/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="/social/services/templates/testingdifferentversion8/js/foundation.dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
              window.addEvent('load', function() {
              new JCaption('img.caption');
        });
     </script>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $( ".button-group li a" ).addClass( "button" );
       $( ".readmore").addClass("small button");
       $( ".menubottom-menu li").addClass("inline-list left");   
       $( ".programs" ).attr( 'data-dropdown','drop1' );
       $( ".small").addClass("f-dropdown");
       $( ".small").attr('id', 'drop1');
       $( ".f-dropdown").attr('data-dropdown-content', '');
      });
  </script>
```

**EDIT 2**

Am posting results of javascript's console ...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'append' of null foundation.min.js:13
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined foundation.dropdown.js:183
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foundation' (index):253

Also, just in case there's any misunderstanding of converting from $() to jQuery():

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function(){
              jQuery( ".button-group li a" ).addClass( "button" );
              jQuery( ".readmore").addClass("small button");
              jQuery( ".menubottom-menu li").addClass("inline-list left");   
              jQuery( ".programs" ).attr( 'data-dropdown','drop1' );
              jQuery( ".small").addClass("f-dropdown");
              jQuery( ".small").attr('id', 'drop1');
              jQuery( ".f-dropdown").attr('data-dropdown-content', '');
              jQuery( "li .item-107 a").removeClass("button");
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: Did you try using `jQuery()` instead of the dollar `$()` in your code? What error do you get in the console?

Comment: @Sergio, yes, I changed that bottom script of $() to jQuery. Still no dice. Looked at the javascript console in Chrome, and am posting results in post.

Comment: @Sergio, do you think based on my javascript's console results, it's not getting initialized?

Comment: I am not familiar with foundation, but yes its not loading properly. If you have a live link please post. If not someone else I can check tomorrow. Btw, try using this order in your script loading: `jQuery first, Mootools 2nd, Foundation 3rd`.

Comment: @Sergio, hey, letting you know that I've finally got it working the past hour. Sorry, had to leave this alone for a while. Just fyi, it was the suggestion of putting foundation after jQuery that ultimately solved it, as per the commenter's suggestion below. Thank you though for taking the time to try to help me to figure it out. Much appreciated. =)

Comment: Great! I know Mootools adapts to not use the dollar ($), it detects if its used. I saw also that Foundation does also, in the first lines of the script. Just curious: did you get error with the order of scripts I suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this are the only causes to your problem:

1. you need to include foundation *after* jQuery.
2. This script:

   ```
   <script>
      jQuery(document).foundation();
   </script>
   ```

   should be after the foundation.js.  All scripts should be at the bottom of the page so if you inserted it before the `<body>` tag, it won't work; but it will if you have your scripts in the `<head>`.  I have it working [here](http://greyge.tmg.it/) take a look.
3. I don't think you need the mootools/core.js; if so, then try to get rid of them as they only make debugging more difficult.  If you need mootools, switch all `$` to the explicit `jQuery` to ensure you're calling jQuery and not mootools.

Comment: just letting you know that it was your first suggestion that made it work. The script tag placed before body tag works, fyi. Also, with mootools, it works. Though I've removed it as it's unnecessary. Was curious to see what worked, and what didn't, and am passing it on. Thank you for your troubleshooting help.